# check is there any links exists in text box using regex

Tags: jquery

I have a text box. In that text box, I want to allow letters numbers and few symbols (.,').

- I don't allow any links in that text box.  I want regex to don't allow links like (HTTP, HTTP, WWW, and FTP).
- I am using the below regex. Its working fine when the text box starts with WWW. If the WWW word includes in the middle of the text, then it
  is not working.

  [^HTTP|ftp|HTTP|WWW]

Comment: If you allow only `.,'` then it's not possible to put url with schema, because it follows with `://`

Comment: Apart from that you cant use `[…]` here because it matches all the characters in it. You could use a negative lookbehind or something like that.

Comment: i just want to check www or http text exists or not

Comment: Yes and this will not work with a simple character matching.

Answer (score 0):

This one working fine for me.

^(?!.*(?=.*www)|(?=.*http)).*$